# SharedPreferences in Flutter

Tags: flutter, authentication, flutter-sharedpreference

I'm having trouble getting certain items from an array and saving them in SharedPreferences.

[This is my login function, where it returns a body with all the user information.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nAlq.png)

I store the whole array inside my SharedPreferences but I can't access the items separately. I need them separated, as I want to show the name of the logged in user on another screen, etc.

[This is the print of "resposta.body"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dIxg.png)

**login_widget.dart**

The login function is on bottom

```
import 'package:biolivre2/cadastro_usuario/cadastro_usuario_widget.dart';
import 'package:biolivre2/index.dart';
import 'package:biolivre2/services/service-prefs.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class LoginWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginWidgetState createState() => _LoginWidgetState();
}

bool _isObscure = false;

class _LoginWidgetState extends State<LoginWidget> {
  final _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _senhaController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    bool _isObscure = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 5, 45, 106),
      body: Form(
        key: _formkey,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  maxWidth: 800,
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 80, 0, 0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Image.asset(
                            'assets/images/logo-livre.png',
                            width: 130,
                            height: 130,
                            fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 30, 20, 0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          controller: _emailController,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Email',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              ),
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 5, 45, 106),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.white, width: 1.56),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.white, width: 1.56),
                              )),
                          validator: (email) {
                            if (email == null || email.isEmpty) {
                              return 'Por favor, digite seu e-mail';
                            } else if (!RegExp(
                                    r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")
                                .hasMatch(_emailController.text)) {
                              return 'Por favor, digite um e-mail correto';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Padding(
                          padding:
                              EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 8)),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10, 20, 0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          controller: _senhaController,
                          obscureText: _isObscure,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(_isObscure
                                      ? Icons.visibility_off
                                      : Icons.visibility),
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _isObscure = !_isObscure;
                                    });
                                  }),
                              labelText: 'Senha',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              ),
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 5, 45, 106),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.white, width: 1.56),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.white, width: 1.56),
                              )),
                          validator: (senha) {
                            if (senha == null || senha.isEmpty) {
                              return 'Por favor, digite uma senha';
                            } else if (senha.length < 6) {
                              return "Por favor, digite uma senha com mais de 6 caracteres";
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 20),
                            child: TextButton(
                              onPressed: () async {
                                FocusNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

                                if (_formkey.currentState.validate()) {
                                  var valido = await login();

                                  if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
                                    currentFocus.unfocus();
                                  }
                                  if (valido) {
                                    verificaUser();
                                  } else {
                                    _senhaController.clear();
                                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                        .showSnackBar(snackBar);
                                  }
                                }
                              },
                              child: const Text("Login"),
                              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                fixedSize: const Size(150, 50),
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                primary: Colors.black,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 20),
                            child: Container(
                              child: const Text(
                                  "Ainda não um tem cadastro?\n"
                                  "Clique no botão abaixo",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                      color: Colors.white)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                            child: TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  PageTransition(
                                    type: PageTransitionType.fade,
                                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                                    reverseDuration:
                                        Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                                    child: CadastroUsuarioWidget(),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                              child: const Text("Cadastrar"),
                              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                fixedSize: const Size(150, 50),
                                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                                primary: Colors.white,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  final snackBar = const SnackBar(
    content: Text(
      "Email ou senha incorretos",
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
  );

  Future<bool> login() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    SharedPreferences usuario = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    var email = _emailController.text;
    var senha = _senhaController.text;
    var auth = 'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$email:$senha'));
    var url = Uri.parse("http://177.70.102.109:3005/autenticacao");

    var resposta = await http.get(
      url,
      headers: (<String, String>{'authorization': auth}),
    );
    print(resposta.body);

    if (resposta.statusCode == 200) {
      await sharedPreferences.setString(
          'token', "Token ${jsonDecode(resposta.body)['token']}");
      await usuario.setString(
          'usuario', "Usuario ${jsonDecode(resposta.body)['usuario']}");

      print(usuario);

      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  verificaUser() async {
    //trocar por nivel usuario logado
    var email = _emailController.text;

    if (email == "admin@kitlivre.com") {
      await Navigator.push(
        context,
        PageTransition(
          type: PageTransitionType.fade,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          reverseDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          child: InicioUsuarioWidget(),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      await Navigator.push(
        context,
        PageTransition(
          type: PageTransitionType.fade,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          reverseDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          child: InicioUsuarioWidget(),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

**Json**

```
[
    {
        "nome": "",
        "email": "",
        "data_de_nascicmento": "1900-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "documento": "",
        "telefone_fixo": null,
        "telefone_celular": null,
        "cep": "",
        "logradouro": "",
        "numero": "",
        "complemento": "",
        "bairro": "",
        "cidade": "",
        "estado": "",
        "situacao_lesao": "",
        "nivel_lesao": "",
        "detalhe_lesao": "",
        "foto_documento": "",
        "foto_com_documento": "",
        "foto_reconhecimento": null,
        "foto_documento64": null,
        "foto_com_documento64": null,
        "foto_reconhecimento64": null,
        "nivel": 1,
        "senha": "$2a$10$22bLU3zd7Ry8JoqcXuePieNdHrvqQklSvIe9nN6nOF1l30D5e47b2",
        "telefone": "",
        "sobrenome": "",
        "ativo": true,
        "id": 1,
        "tipo_usuario": "USUÁRIO",
        "painel_de_gerenciamento": false,
        "atualizar_equipamentos": false,
        "estoque_de_equipamentos": false,
        "solicitacao_de_equipamentos": true,
        "devolucao_de_equipamentos": true
    }]
```

Comment: It will be much better if you copy-paste your code snippet instead of image

Comment: Decode the value from sharedPreference then you can access them separately